# What physical laws differs in non inertial frame

Tags: special-relativity, laws-of-physics

For me physical laws should be observers independent, what should be depend on the observers are measurements. 
But one of the postulates of  Special relativity is that all laws of physics should be the same for all inertial frame.

My is question is , for non inertial observers what are the physical laws that are not the same?

Comment: It's probably impossible to provide a complete list, since that depends heavily on which facts in particular you're calling "physical laws".

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/479727/2451

Comment: Just as an example, in a rotating frame of reference you get "fictitious" centrifugal and coriolis forces, giving different "physical" laws to a non-rotating frame.

Comment: As an aside, I would not describe physical law as caring about your frame of reference. The mathematical and conceptual structure we use to work out the consequences of physical law differ, but physics remains what it is.